# Is there a way to filter numbers in a html page?

Tags: html, excel, google-chrome, filter, numbers

it's for work so i can't disclose details, but basicly orders come in and they get listed via a external website. the thing i want to do is to list them so i can copy them easily. i've been searching for a way to export the page to excel, but this didn't work out. now i'm looking into devtools for chrome to filter them out.
what i'm looking for is a way to filter a bunch of numbers from a page, and quickly be able to copy them. it doesn't really matter how. below i added a picture to show the overall scructure of the page itself.
All suggestions are welcome!

[image]

greetings, niels

Comment: You can inspect the element by right clicking, find the class or the id of the numbers (element) and then through console you can do that.

If you could share the website URL, we may help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can with Javascript.

However, the image you provided does not contain the necessary information to help solve your exact question.

1. Get the element that contains the value that you want to receive via element inspect in your browser.
2. Use `.innerText` to retrieve the value inside of the element.

For example, let's say I want to fetch your Stackoverflow username from this post, here's how that would go (you can copy paste the code in your web-console to see the result):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('user-details')[0].childNodes[2].innerText
```

The same principle applies to numbers or other values/data. Without the page structure, it is impossible to give you a concrete answer to your question. Hopefully the above gives you some guidance as to what you should be looking for.

Comment: Thanks! i finally figured it out